# How do i use XDM to download youtube videos on 16.04LTS?

Tags: downloads, youtube

I copied and pasted the url, but the downloded file is in html , not in video format.

Comment: Do you just want some means to download YouTube videos or do you specifically want the software you're used to work?

Answer (score 2):

- Videos are stored in the server which youtube connects to load the video. To download the video, you have to enter the URL of the server where the actual video is stored.
- You can get the address of the original video using addons like `flashgot`.
- Here, I'm going to explain How to download youtube videos using uget (you can choose your integration with XDM) and `flashgot`.
- Goto youtube.com and find you video.
  [image: Flashgot]
- On top right corner you will see `flashgot icon`.
- If you want to download hd720p/mp4 it's first, whereas hd1080p/mp4 is sixth. It is important to remember the number.
- After you click on the shown icon it will give the following dialog [image: Flashgot]
- Choose `Mark None` and select the number you wished to download. Mine was hd720p/mp4 (i.e.1).
- Hit `OK` and you are good to go.

Comment: Ask any question related to the post. I use uget not XDM. But, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: warning: When you go to the flashgot icon on the top right corner, don't click it at first, wait for the black list to appear.